# I want to store the name of the selected index in a variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to do that there is a list of drop down whatever I select from that dropdownlist, I want to store that thing in  the variable. Please help me out . It is in mvc or asp.net
code is

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Ambassadors", new SelectList(new SAP.GS.Toolkit.BusinessComponents.AmbassadorBC().GetAllAmbassadors(), "AmbassadorID", "FullName"))
```

Comment: Do you mean in the browser using javascript?

Comment: hmmm ya i want to store in a variable in javascript as I want to output the name of the ambassador he is selecting

Comment: Output to where? Do you want to post back the `FullName` as well as `AmbassadorID` of the selected `Ambassador`?

Comment: yes I want to post the full name only of the selected ambassador

Comment: Then you can just change the `SelectList` second parameter to `"FullName"` (same as 3rd parameter). Your model property `string Ambassadors` will then contain the `FullName` of the selected `Ambassador` on postback

Comment: but select list is for the dropdownloast iof I will delete that then how dropdown will come could you please tell me through code what u r saying

Answer (score 1):

implement "onchange" javascript for dropdownlist and get the value of selected item in the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post back **both** the value and display text (`AmbassadorID` and `FullName`), create a hidden input to store the `FullName` property, and update the value using javascript

View

```
<input type="hidden" id="AmbassadorName" name="AmbassadorName" />
```

Script

```
$('#Ambassador').change(function() {
  $('#AmbassadorName').val($(this).children(':selected').text();
});
// trigger change on page load
$('#Ambassador').trigger('change');
```

Now when you post back, the value of `AmbassadorName` will be the `FullName` of the selected ambassador.  You can retrieve this from FormCollection (e.g. `Request.Form["AmbassadorName"];`, by adding an additional parameter to you post method or by adding the property `AmbassadorName` to you view model.

If on the other hand you only want to post back the the `FullName`, then you html helper should be

```
@Html.DropDownList("Ambassadors", new SelectList(new SAP.GS.Toolkit.BusinessComponents.AmbassadorBC().GetAllAmbassadors(), "FullName", "FullName"))
```

Now when you post back, the value of your property `Ambassadors` is the `FullName` of the selected ambassador.